# How to get user photo to appear in node panel

Tags: users, panels, media

I'm overriding a node template with panels, I'm trying to add the user photo, but the only thing I can seem to add is the username. Does anyone know how to do this? do I have to do something weird like create a mini-panel that loads the user?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jumped the gun and posted this question before I really messed around with it. All you have to do is add  "User From Node" as a relationship in contexts, then it will show up as picture in panels